# Why can't Visual Studio 2017 find installed .NET Core SDKs?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have a simple project which builds with "dotnet build" and with msbuild from the Visual Studio 2019 Developer prompt, but not from the Visual Studio 2017 prompt or IDE. I would like to understand how msbuild 15 finds the installed SDKs and why they are not up to date, while msbuild 16 in VS 2019 works ok.

It appears that the .NET Core SDKs are not registered with msbuild 15 but I don't know how that registration occurs. I have tried reinstalling the SDK, installing different versions of the SDK, but no luck so far.

Unfortunately just switching to 2019 is difficult because what I really want is to compile a large code base with a build script which assumes 2017 - this is a cut-down repro.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Compiling from VS2017 developer prompt:

```
msbuild foo.csproj /nologo
Build started 5/20/2019 7:22:06 AM.
Project "C:\Users\edwin\Source\Repos\foo\foo.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrame
workInference.targets(112,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0.  Either target .NET Cor
e 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.0. [C:\Users\edwin\Source\Repos\foo\foo.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\edwin\Source\Repos\foo\foo.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Compiling in same window with "dotnet build" succeeds, as does "msbuild foo.csproj" in the 2019 developer prompt (which uses msbuild 16).

dotnet --info shows

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.204
 Commit:    8757db13ec

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.204\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.5
  Commit:  0a3c9209c0

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.604 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Comment: You have SDK version 2.2.204 so targeting netcoreapp2.2 instead of netcoreapp2.0 is worth trying.

Comment: Thanks! However, when you go to download the .NET Core 2.0 SDK for VS 2017 (from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks ) it points you to the 2.1.202 SDK, which I have installed; and the package builds when targeting netcoreapp2.0 when using 'dotnet build'. So I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue 4 days ago when I was using Visual Studio 2017. And I spent all the days to solve it. After searching, on internet,I realised that it was a versioning issue. 
verytime, I tried to create a new project I had this message:

```
The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

So, I decided to delete all the .Net Core SDK versions and installed the compatible one as indicated on the [download Page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). See the image below.

[[image: Right .Net core version[2]]

After installing it, everything started working fine.

Comment: would like to know where you delete the dot net core sdk? my projects dont require dot net core at all, yet i still see the prompt "Could not install the .Dot.Net Core 2.1" -.-

Comment: Go to the control panel, then uninstall it.